# when accessing teacher(1,2) why it doesn't execute both names khan and taj?

Tags: matlab

The MATLAB code

```
teacher(1)=struct('FirstName','Sohaib','LastName','Khan');                             
teacher(2)=struct( 'FirstName','Murtaza','LastName','Taj');   
disp(teacher(1,2).LastName(1:end))
```

creates the output `Taj`. Why are not both names `Khan` and `Taj` displayed?

Comment: The reference `teacher(1,2)` refers the the second element (`Taj`) only.  To refer to both, use `disp([teacher(:).LastName])`.

Answer (score 2):

With `teacher(1,2)` you access the element in the first column and the second row of `teacher`. This is the entry with `Taj`. With `LastName(1:end)` you only access the name of the teacher you selected with `teacher(1,2)`.

To display the names of both teachers, you have to specify the indexes of the teachers inside square brackets `[1,2]`. As `disp` only takes one argument, you have to create an array of names to print.

```
disp([teacher([1,2]).LastName])
```